# MySQL using COUNT as total and avoiding exceeding a maximum

Tags: php, mysql

I was tasked to create this organization registration system. I decided to use MySQL and PHP to do it. Each organization in table `orgs` has a `max_members` column and has a unique id `org_id`. Each student in table `students` has an `org` column. Every time a student joins an organization, his `org` column is equated to the `org_id` of that organization.

When someone clicks join on an organization page, a PHP file executes.

In the PHP file, a query retrieves the total number of students whose `org` is equal to the `org_id` of the organization being joined.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(student_id) FROM students WHERE org = '$org_id'";
```

The maximum members is also retrieved from the `orgs` table.

```
$query = "SELECT max_members FROM orgs WHERE org_id = '$org_id'";
```

So I have variables `$total_members` and `$max_members`. A basic if statement checks if `$total_members < $max_members`, then updates the student's `org` equal to the `org_id`. If not, then it does nothing and notifies the student that the organization is full.

What my main concern is what if this situation happened:

```
Org A only has one slot left. 29/30 members.
Student A clicks join on Org A (and at the same time)
Student B clicks join on Org A
Student A retrieves data: There is one slot left
Student B retrieves data: There is one slot left
Student A's org = Org A's org_id
Student B's org = Org A's org_id
After the scripts have executed, Org A will show up with 31/30 members
```

Can this happen? If yes, how can I avoid it?

I've thought about using MySQL variables like this:

```
SET @org_id = 'what-ever-org';
SELECT @total_members := COUNT(student_id) FROM students WHERE org_main = @org_id;
SELECT @max_members := max_members FROM orgs WHERE org_id = @org_id;
UPDATE students SET org_main = IF(@total_members < @max_members, @org_id, '') WHERE student_id = 99999;
```

But I don't know if it would make a difference.

*Row locking does not apply in my case. I think. I'd love to be proven wrong though.*

*The code I've written above is a simplified version of the original code. The original code included checking registration dates, org days, etc, however, these things are not related to the question.*

Comment: The count is done in the same script as the INSERT? Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Each student has his own row in the table `students`. The script only contains `UPDATE` and `SELECT` queries. I'm using InnoDB and there is only one script!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is usually called a race-condition. It occurs, because you perform two non-atomic operations on your database. To avoid this you need to use transactions, which ensure that the database server prevents this kind of interference. Another approach would be to use a "before update trigger".

#### Transaction

As you're using MySQL you have to make sure that the DB engine your tables are running on is InnoDB, because MyISAM just doesn't have transactions. Before you do your `SELECT`  you need to start a transaction. Either send `START TRANSACTION` manually to the database or use a proper PHP implementation for it, e.g. PDO ([PDO::beginTransaction()](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.begintransaction.php)).

In a running transaction you can then use the suffix `FOR UPDATE` in your `SELECT` statement, which will lock the rows that have been selected by the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(student_id) FROM students WHERE org = :orgId FOR UPDATE
```

After your `UPDATE` statement you can commit the transaction, which will write the changes permanently to the database and remove the locks.

If you expect a lot of these simultaneous requests to happen, be aware that locking can cause some delay in the response, because the database might wait for a lock to be released.

#### Trigger

Instead of using transactions you can also create a trigger on the database, which will run before an update is executed on the database. In this trigger you could test if the maximum number of students has been exceeded and throw an error if that's the case. However, this can be a very challenging approach, especially if the value to be checked depends on something in the `UPDATE` statement. Also it is debatable if it's a good idea to implement this kind of logic on the database level.

Comment: I have a line in my PHP script `$db->autocommit(false);`. In the link you shared, it said that beginTransaction() "Turns off autocommit mode". Does `$db->autocommit(false);` do the same thing?

Comment: Yes and no. It does turn of the auto commit, but it also does a lot of other stuff as well. So they are not the same operation at all.

Comment: I've thought about locking rows. But which ones? If I lock the rows where org = org_id, it wouldn't really matter since I wouldn't update those rows anyway. What I'm worried about is two clients accessing the same data and updating their own rows at the same time.

Comment: You need to lock all rows basically, because any change to any row can change the member count of any organization. If a student switches the organization, one counter would be decreased, one increased. And this could happen to any organization, so locking based on the orgId will not be enough.

Comment: Would this still be advisable if the table `students` has over 2300 rows?

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer by the way!

Comment: Unless you reach millions of rows, the database should have absolutely no problem with this kind of operation. It has been built to do this. Also, your operations are not really so complex that there will be much delay between lock and release. It was just a hint that this might cause some delay. You basically need to make you operation atomic, so nothing can slip in between. Using a stored procedure (as @ShailPandey suggested) would also be a solution to achieve this, but it splits your logic up to be in two places.

Comment: Will test the database performance when locking the whole table later. Will also research Stored Procedures. Seems interesting. Thanks again for everything!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, use synchronized function in PHP which performs this operation. But if you want to implement all the logic in MySQL (I'd like this method), please use Stored Procedure.

Create a stored procedure as (not exactly):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE join_org(stu_id int, org_id, int, OUT success int)

DECLARE total_members int;
DECLARE max_members_Allowed;

SELECT COUNT(student_id) INTO total_members FROM students WHERE org = 'org_id';
SELECT max_members INTO max_members_Allowed FROM orgs WHERE org_id = 'org_id';

IF(max_members_Allowed > total_members) Then
      UPDATE student SET orgid='org_id';
      SET success = 1;
ELSE
 SET success = 0;
END IF;
```

Then register this out variable named 'success' int your PHP code to indicate success or failure. Call this procedure when user clicks join.

Comment: PHP has no support for synchronized functions as far as I'm aware. Did that change at some point or did you only mean that as a general "if available, use them"?

Comment: Ok, I am not a PHP developer(I use JSP instead). But I have seen $this->synchronized(function($thread) somewhere. What does it mean ?

Comment: I've never seen this before. Might be part of some framework that I don't know. There might be some extensions for PHP (like PECL Threads or the Semaphores) that could be used to get there, but in the core PHP doesn't have support for synchronized calls, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, please visit http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/thread.synchronized.php

Comment: Yeah...as I said, it's part of an extension called "pthreads" (or "PECL Threads"). It's not activated by default. In any case...your solution using a stored procedure is good and probably solved the problem nicely. Only issue is that people often don't like to store logic in the database, because then you don't have everything in one place (i.e. in the source code).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will consider this!